# Zero width space in XSL gives stackoverflow error

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm using FOP 1.1, i've a text which can contain upto 20,000 characters and since there was text which didn't contain any spaces in between have modified the xsl to use the zero width space. It works fine if the xml tag contains around 1500 characters, if it is more than that i'm getting stack overflow error. Heap Space in weblogic server is also 2 GB.
Can anyone help on this with a possible workaround or if there is any flaws in the xsl.

Below is the xsl code sample  -

```
    <xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    xmlns:locale="xalan://java.util.Locale" 
    xmlns:arrayList="xalan://java.util.ArrayList" 
    xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions" extension-element-prefixes="func"
    version="1.0">

..................




     <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="func:callTemplate(summaryData)"/>
        </fo:block>

..................
    <xsl:template name="zero_width_space_1">
            <xsl:param name="data"/>
            <xsl:param name="counter" select="0"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$counter &lt; (string-length($data))">
                    <xsl:value-of select='concat(substring($data,$counter,1),"&#8203;")'/>
                    <xsl:call-template name="zero_width_space_2">
                        <xsl:with-param name="data" select="$data"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="counter" select="$counter+1"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template name="zero_width_space_2">
            <xsl:param name="data"/>
            <xsl:param name="counter"/>
            <xsl:value-of select='concat(substring($data,$counter,1),"&#8203;")'/>
            <xsl:call-template name="zero_width_space_1">
                <xsl:with-param name="data" select="$data"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="counter" select="$counter+1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>


        <func:function name="func:callTemplate">
            <xsl:param name="string1"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="zero_width_space_1">
                <xsl:with-param name="data" select="$string1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <func:result/>
        </func:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Below is the error which i'm getting -

> Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError   at
>   org.apache.xml.utils.FastStringBuffer.append(FastStringBuffer.java:499)
>     at
>   org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.dom2dtm.DOM2DTM.getNodeData(DOM2DTM.java:935)
>     at
>   org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.dom2dtm.DOM2DTM.getNodeData(DOM2DTM.java:928)
>     at
>   org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.dom2dtm.DOM2DTM.getStringValue(DOM2DTM.java:827)
>     at
>   org.apache.xpath.objects.XNodeSet.getStringFromNode(XNodeSet.java:217)
>     at org.apache.xpath.objects.XNodeSet.xstr(XNodeSet.java:256)    at
>   org.apache.xpath.functions.FunctionDef1Arg.getArg0AsString(FunctionDef1Arg.java:97)
>     at
>   org.apache.xpath.functions.FuncStringLength.execute(FuncStringLength.java:45)
>     at org.apache.xpath.Expression.execute(Expression.java:155)     at
>   org.apache.xpath.operations.Operation.execute(Operation.java:110)     at
>   org.apache.xpath.Expression.bool(Expression.java:186)     at
>   org.apache.xpath.XPath.bool(XPath.java:412)   at
>   org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemChoose.execute(ElemChoose.java:126)    at
>   org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
>     at
>   org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemTemplate.execute(ElemTemplate.java:394)
>     at
>   org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemCallTemplate.execute(ElemCallTemplate.java:248)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am confused by the need for two templates here, as you could combine the logic into one, like so

```
<xsl:template name="zero_width_space_1">
    <xsl:param name="data"/>
    <xsl:param name="counter" select="0"/>
    <xsl:if test="$counter &lt;= (string-length($data))">
        <xsl:value-of select='concat(substring($data,$counter,1),"&#8203;")'/>
        <xsl:call-template name="zero_width_space_1">
            <xsl:with-param name="data" select="$data"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="counter" select="$counter+1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Also note, your function is not quite right, it should look like this...

```
<func:function name="func:callTemplate">
    <xsl:param name="string1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="result">
        <xsl:call-template name="zero_width_space_1">
            <xsl:with-param name="data" select="$string1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <func:result select="$result" />
</func:function>
```

I am not sure if that will solve your stack overflow issue. However, if the purpose is to insert a `&#8203;` before each character, then you could make use of the `tokenize` function available in exslt

```
<func:function name="func:callTemplate">
    <xsl:param name="string1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="result">
        <xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize($string1, '')">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#8203;', .)" />
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#8203;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    <func:result select="$result" />
</func:function>
```

Comment: Hi tim,
i've tried using single template too, but as u said it didn't resolve the stack overflow error. 
am not much aware of the FOP, i tried with some solution mentioned in other posts about ways to wrap the text using zero width space.
will try with the solution u provided.
thanks for the quick response..

Comment: tim i tried with the function you gave, but i'm getting below error -

SystemId Unknown; Line #3951; Column #66; Could not find function: replace
SystemId Unknown; Line #3951; Column #66; function token not found.

am using fop 1.1

Comment: My apologies. My solution using `replace` was for XSLT 2.0 only. I've now amended my answer to give a solution that works in XSLT 1.0 using exslt's string functions. See it in action at http://xsltransform.net/jxDigUZ

Comment: Hi tim, even with stringtokenizer approach, same problem.. getting stackoverflow error

Comment: Try changing the function to return the value without change; `<func:function name="func:callTemplate"><xsl:param name="string1"/><func:result select="$string1" /></func:function>`. That will determine whether it is the function that is causing the stackoverflow or not.

Comment: tim, i've 3 text blocks where i need to introduce zero width space..
For all the 3 block, max size is 20,000.. 
If all the 3 block is having 20,000 characters in xml then its leading to stackoverflow error. 
If only 1 block is having 20,000 characters then it's working properly without any error.

Comment: Do you still get the stack overflow exception when you change the function to just return the unchanged string?

Comment: tim i tried changing the function, everything gets displayed now without any error. 20,000 characters is getting displayed in all the 3 blocks..

Comment: Hi tim, 
thank you very much.. The string tokenizer solution u gave is working as expected when tried it in weblogic server.. It was failing in tomcat server ..